# Can not get function to work

Tags: c++

I want when this function is ran (Monster.cpp)

```
void Monster::addWeapon(typeOfWeapon selection){
    cout<<myWeaponSelection<<endl; //out puts correctly.
    myWeaponSelection[0].getWeapon(selection); //gives error    
}
```

that it would run this function (weapon.cpp)

```
void getWeapon(typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection)
{
    cout<<"you got weapon!"<<myWeaponSelection<<endl
}
```

ERROR: 
monster.cpp(126) : error C2228: left of '.getWeapon' must have class/struct/union

Monster.h

```
#ifndef MONSTER
#define MONSTER
#include <string>
using namespace std;
enum typeOfMonster {dog,wolf,bear,goat,human,god,snail,elephant,wayven,bird,worm,kid,boy,ent,superman};

class Monster
{
    public:
    Monster();
    ~Monster(){}

    typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection[2];
    void addWeapon(typeOfWeapon weaponName);
};
#endif
```

Weapon.h

```
#ifndef WEAPON
#define WEAPON
#include <string>
using namespace std;
enum typeOfWeapon {bark,howel,eat,ram,shoot,smite,slime,stomp,peck,swarm,dig,bow,slingshot,kick,beem, //wp 1
                    bite,charm,claw,naw,burn,lighingstrike,heal,smack,lazers,poop,posion,superkick,punch,tackel,freeze};//wp 2
class Weapon
{
    public:
    Weapon();
    ~Weapon(){}

    typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection;
    void getWeapon(typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection,int whichWeapon); 
};
#endif
```

How to fix?

Comment: The compiler is preventing you from creating monsters :)

Comment: It is just a mess... I think you should spend some time finding a intro book of C++, read about the chapter about class.  It seems that you don't really know what you are doing here.

Comment: Excellent observation ,  I am learning and btw your message is a mess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `typeOfWeapon` is an enum. It does not have member function.

If you want to add a new weapon to `myWeaponSelection`, you can do :

```
void Monster::addWeapon(typeOfWeapon selection)
{
    cout << myWeaponSelection << endl;
    myWeaponSelection[0] = selection;
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

because `myWeaponSelection[0]` and `selection` are of the same type.

And your getWeapon should be in the `Weapon` scope :

```
void Weapon::getWeapon( typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection );
```

not

```
void getWeapon( typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection );
```

Comment: ok the scope part worked, for that error  as for the weapon selection i have to rewrite function, cause i want when the selection is add, it adds data to that weapon like power, range ect.. but that maybe a new question later..

Comment: I think you should rewrite the relation between the monsters and weapons. Because What I think you want is to store a weapon in/for the monster right ?

Comment: yea, going to try and rewrite it

Answer (score 3):

You have a non member function in your `Weapon.cpp`:

```
void getWeapon(typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection)
```

You need to put is in the `Weapon` scope:

```
void Weapon::getWeapon(typeOfWeapon myWeaponSelection)
//   ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: this was it, i gave you answer cause you where first.. thanks

Comment: @GlenMorse the other answer is more complete. For the sake of future visitors, it would be better to select that one. I was too lazy to read through all your code and stopped at the first error :-)